# How do I format Content-Range header for Upload Session Microsoft Graph API

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am running into an issue uploading files to an upload session using v1.0 Microsoft Graph API. 
My steps:

1. Get Access Token: Success
2. Select File / Create Upload Session: Success (I get back an uploadUrl to upload the bytes)
3. Upload Bytes to uploadUrl: Fail with below error.

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
{
   "error": 
   {
      "code":"invalidRequest",
      "message":"The Content-Range header is missing or malformed."
   }
}
```

I have tried using the following formats and I still receive the same error.

```
"bytes 0-100/100"
"0-100/100"
"0-100"
```

I am following this article from Mircosoft https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createuploadsession

Here is my function that uploads to the uploadUrl retreived from creating the upload session

```
public uploadToSession(file: HTMLInputElement, session: any, fileData: any) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Length', fileData.length); //(ie: "100")
    headers.append('Content-Range', fileData.range); //(ie: "bytes 0-100/100")
    this.http.put(session.uploadUrl, { headers })
        .subscribe(
            (res: Response) => console.log(res),
            error => console.log(error)
        );
}
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: The idea behind this API is that you are sending chunks right? So it works expect the total file size to be larger than one chunk, i.e. `bytes 0-50/100` followed by `bytes 50-100/100`.

Comment: That is correct that the API is designed to allow chucks to be sent, however, from my understanding you could also send the whole file as long as the size is less than 60 MiB. Have you seen documentation stating that you cannot send the whole file at once? I am trying to avoid using two different upload methods depending on the size, but if that is the only way then so be it.

Comment: No - I couldn't find anything, but your code looks good so I was innovating potential problems that might occur

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `Content-Range` header has the following format:

```
Content-Range: bytes <startindex>-<endindex>/<totallength>
```

Your issue appears to be a mixing of indexes (0-based) and lengths (1-based). For a 100-byte file your header would need to look like:

```
Content-Range: bytes 0-99/100
```

Comment: Thank you, Brad. Should that value be a string?

Comment: `content.Headers.ContentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue( 0, source.Length-1, source.Length);`

Comment: the MDN documentation on the content range header implies you can use `*/*` but this doesn't work for me. specifying it fully as above worked OK